# CSS Float with absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position

Consider following example:

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQX3/5/)

How would it be possible to make the `h2` element float to the right side of the image whilst staying over it (therefore having an absolute position) ?

Comment: consider referencing an image that exists. Hard to tell what's happening there when the image you want things floated over is broken

Comment: hmm the image is uploaded on a website. I do see it in jsfiddle. You don't?

Comment: It's there now. Looks you have your answer anyhow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your absolute positioning isn't the problem. Your `<h2>` is 100% of the width of it's parent, which is 100% the width of the page. If you display `.image` using `inline-block`, it will only take up the width of the image and you can align your `<span>`s within the header:

```
.image { 
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

h2 { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 160px; 
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQX3/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `position:absolute;` and set `right:0px;` or what ever you want for right side spacing..

Answer (score 0):

I don't advice to use these spacer spans just use padding or margin to achieve what you have visually in mind.

```
.image { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 160px;
}
.image h2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
.image img { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.image h2 span { 
  color: white; 
  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
  letter-spacing: -1px;  
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px; 
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZQK9x/13/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZQK9x/13//show/

Answer (score -1):

dont seem to get ur requirement :

[is this what u want?](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQX3/9/)

```
h2 {
     position:absolute;
     top:10px;
     width: 100%;
     border:1px solid red;
     text-align:right
 }
```

**After downvote**

[this is what u need](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQX3/17/)

first : instead of `.image`, use `img` tag in your css

```
img {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     /* for IE 6 */
 }
```

second : if setting a child dimension in percentage, make sure parent has it set too....`body,html` in this case

```
body,html{
     width: 100%;
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: that doesn't get positioned within the image's bounds, but rather outside it

Comment: @astralmaster : mate...first ur fiddle was not working, i updated...second : http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQX3/17/...assign css classes correctly

Comment: I used .image to specifically reference that element. Using img might be wrong in some cases. eg. when you need to apply settings to specific image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48510/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-astralmaster)

Comment: @astralmaster : i just wanted to let u know that css style and html markup should be in sync...nothing else!! :)